# Alternate hypothesis being "less," "greater," or "two-sided"

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, python

Often times, in python's scipy library's statistical tests(e.g. [Fisher Exact Test)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisher_exact.html), there is an option for two-tailed or single tailed. But for single-tailed it says "less" or "greater." I don't quite understand what it means when it states:

> Use a one-sided alternative hypothesis (also known as a directional hypothesis) to determine whether the population parameter differs from the hypothesized value in a specific direction. You can specify the direction to be either greater than or less than the hypothesized value. [Source](http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab-express/1/help-and-how-to/basic-statistics/inference/supporting-topics/basics/null-and-alternative-hypotheses/)

Can someone please clarify this? What do they mean by direction? If I have a one tailed distribution with the mean close to 0 and no negative values, then what exactly would "less" do and "greater" do?

Here's an example of my frequency dist. [image]

The x-axis is **# of samples** and y-axis is **number of components of interest** and each sample is an image.

Comment: Mean zero and no negative values would imply your distribution has all mass at 0.

Comment: I've edited the OP. It's close to 0. In other words, my data might fifteen 0s and four or five values between 1-3. @MichaelM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisher Exact Tests consider all possible permutations of $2 \times 2$ contingency tables. Each table permutation can be ranked in terms of its degree of association by considering the odds ratio. An odds ratio which is greater than 1 shows a positive association between an exposure and an outcome whereas an OR less than 1 shows a negative association.

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
& D & \bar{D} & \text{Total} \\ \hline
E & a & b& a+b\\
\bar{E} & c& d& c+d\\
\text{Total} & a+c& b+d& n=a+b+c+d\\
\end{array} \qquad OR = (ad)/(bc)
$$

The null hypothesis of a two sided Fisher's Exact Test is that the odds ratio of outcome and an exposure is 1 whereas the alternative is that it is not 1. A single sided test has a null hypothesis that the odds ratio is either less than 1 or greater than 1.

Comment: So how should I know what to set for the null hypothesis: less or greater? In other words, is it possible for you to please state how to make the decision to set the null hypothesis with regards to less/greater than in layman terms without bringing in odds ratio?

Comment: @Christian if you do not know, you probably want to run a two tailed test.

Comment: Hmm, I see. But my frequency distributions are clearly one-tailed. As in the OP, it is averaged close to 0, no positive values, and a few positive values.

Comment: I've added a graph to show what I mean. Any ideas? @AdamO

Comment: @Christian your graph makes no sense. Label the axes and describe a "sample".

Comment: Ops, sorry about that, I had to crop it for privacy sake. I've edited the question.